# What's is the name of a js library?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I need to find a js library, which has an opportunity to set a backlight of the image according to it colours. But the google and other's results don't help at all

thank you!

Comment: Why a library?  Just *code* a *function!*

Comment: @Man of Snow, Yes, it is the descision, but it was really a good library, with picturesque effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking of the Adaptive Backgrounds jQuery plugin? It's been trending on github this week.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://briangonzalez.github.io/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js/)**</kbd> <kbd>**[Github](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js)**</kbd>